# EJB and Web service relation

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependencies, ejb-3.0

I have one EAR application. Web service and a Message Driven EJB inside it. I need to deploy it on glassfish server.

With ant I have made an ear witch contains service.war and md-ejb.jar files. Problem is that the EJB class uses some web service's classes which are loaded from spring.

Question: is there a way to use web service's classes as the same dependency for ejb?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong application design. Besides, web and ejb classes have different classloaders. Shared classes, api's, libraries should be packaged into library jars and put into ear's library directory.

META-INF/appplication.xml :

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">

    <module>
        <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>web.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
  <library-directory>libs</library-directory>
</application>
```

Create directory `libs` in ear archive and put there all the shared classes. They will be available both to ejb and web classloaders.